# NOPCommerce AD integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory, nopcommerce

I'm setting up an intranet ecommerce site with NOPCommerce 2.5 and I want the user to be automatically logged on to the site. Everybody on the network is authorized to be customer. Is there an active directory integration for NOPCommerce or does anybody have tips & tricks on how to move forward?

Answer (score 2):

I know that nopCommerce uses their own implementation of the ASP.net Membership Provider. So yes, it is possible to edit that, and have it automatically generate a nopCommerce user via the Network Credentials.

I'm not aware of anything that already exists for this functionality.